# Response code 404 using apache commons

Tags: java, apache, http, http-status-code-404

I'm building a wrapper for an API http://www.sptrans.com.br/desenvolvedores/APIOlhoVivo/Documentacao.aspx?1#docApi-autenticacao (it's in portuguese, but you get the idea).

I'm getting response code 404 when making a POST request and I have no idea why.

This is what is being printed:

> Response Code : 404 {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that
>   matches the request URI
>   'http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0/Login/Autenticar'."}

```
public static String executePost() {
    CloseableHttpClient client =  HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    String targetURL = "http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0/Login/Autenticar";
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token","3de5ce998806e0c0750b1434e17454b6490ccf0a595f3884795da34460a7e7b3"));
    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(targetURL);
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("Response Code : "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) result.append(line);

        System.out.println(result.toString());
        return result.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me from the API documentation (albeit, I can't read Portugese), that the token needs to be in the URL, not POSTed to it:

`POST /Login/Autenticar?token={token}`

I think you are POSTing a form to this endpoint.

You should try this:

```
String targetURL = "http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0/Login/Autenticar?token=3de5ce998806e0c0750b1434e17454b6490ccf0a595f3884795da34460a7e7b3";
```

And don't call `post.setEntity(...)`.

Comment: That was it! I though the point of the post method was exactly to not use the url. I didn't know you could "post nothing". This is the first time I'm dealing with this stuff. Anyway, thanks a lot!!